# How to choose which XML variables ajax sends to html file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xml

I have an XML document, an AJAX script and a HTML script. I want certain values for the XML file passed through to the HTML. What command should I be using to complete the following:

XML Script:

```
    root>
  <coin>
    <trader variable="GLDAG_MAPLE">Gold.co.uk</trader>
    <metal>Silver</metal>
    <type>Maple</type>
    <price>£31.56</price>  **<--- THIS TO BE PASSED THROUGH TO: <td id="001">** 
  </coin>
  <coin>
    <trader variable="GLDAG_BRITANNIA">Gold.co.uk</trader>
    <metal>Silver</metal>
    <type>Britannia</type>
    <price>£32.4</price>  **<---- THIS TO BE PASSED THROUGH TO <td id="002">**
  </coin>
```

AJAX Script:

```
$(response)
    .find("coin")
    .each(function () {
      var _trader = "Trader: " + $(this).find("trader").text();
      console.log(_trader);

      var _metal = "Metal: " + $(this).find("metal").text();
      var _price = "Price: " + $(this).find("price").text();
      var _type = "Type: " + $(this).find("type").text();

      $("#001").text($(this).find('price').text());
      $("#002").text($(this).find('price').text());
      $("#003").text($(this).find('price').text());
      $("#004").text($(this).find('price').text());
      $("#005").text($(this).find('price').text());
      $("#006").text($(this).find('price').text());


      // add content to the HTML
      $("#001").append(_price);         **<--- currently passing through ALL price values**
      $("#002").append(_price);         **<--- also passing through ALL price values** 
    });
```

HTML Script:

```
  <tr>
    <td>**PRICES PLACED BELOW:**</td>
    <td id="001"></td>
    <td id="002"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You posted invalid XML - duplicate xml tags need to be in a container tag. I added `<root></root>` to my example

If you do not want to have your TDs defined before appending:

```js
let  response = `<root>
<coin>
  <trader variable="GLDAG_MAPLE">Gold.co.uk</trader>
  <metal>Silver</metal>
  <type>Maple</type>
  <price>£31.56</price>
</coin>
<coin>
  <trader variable="GLDAG_BRITANNIA">Gold.co.uk</trader>
  <metal>Silver</metal>
  <type>Britannia</type>
  <price>£32.4</price>
</coin>
</root>`;

$table = $("table tbody");
$row = $table.append("<tr/>")
$(response)
    .find("coin")
    .each(function () {
      const _trader = "Trader: " + $(this).find("trader").text();
      console.log(_trader);

      var _metal = "Metal: " + $(this).find("metal").text();
      var _price = "Price: " + $(this).find("price").text();
      var _type = "Type: " + $(this).find("type").text();
      $row.append(`<td>${_price}</td>`)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>**PRICES PLACED BELOW:**</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you DO then

```js
const pad = num => ("00"+num).slice(-3);
let response = `<root>
<coin>
  <trader variable="GLDAG_MAPLE">Gold.co.uk</trader>
  <metal>Silver</metal>
  <type>Maple</type>
  <price>£31.56</price>
</coin>
<coin>
  <trader variable="GLDAG_BRITANNIA">Gold.co.uk</trader>
  <metal>Silver</metal>
  <type>Britannia</type>
  <price>£32.4</price>
</coin>
</root>`;

$(response)
  .find("coin")
  .each(function(i,coin) {
    const _trader = "Trader: " + $(this).find("trader").text();
    console.log(_trader);

    var _metal = "Metal: " + $(this).find("metal").text();
    var _price = "Price: " + $(this).find("price").text();
    var _type = "Type: " + $(this).find("type").text();
    $("#coin"+pad(i)).text(_price)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>**PRICES PLACED BELOW:**</td>
      <td id="coin000"></td>
      <td id="coin001"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I fix my invalid XML. Also what makes it invalid?

Comment: I wrote how. You need to wrap in "<coins>" because you have more than one coin.

Comment: Or your XML you posted is not complete - I see a root> and `<root><coin></coin><coin></coin></root>` is valid, so change my <coins> to <root>

Comment: Yep, i only posted half of the XML as the rest was not relavent. Also is there a way to tell the AJAX to post set coin prices in certain places as my issue is that they need to be displayed on various parts of the page

Comment: see update. You can perhaps use `metal+type` as id?

Comment: Any chance you could help me with editing the code. No experince with working with Javascript TBH.  (https://pastebin.com/9ZikXS9q)?

Comment: What do you need? I need details.

Comment: If you could help modify the script so that it can take the price from the first coin in the XML and place it in a specific <td> in my html and then place the price from the second coin from the XML in another <td> but the <td> it is placed in is defined by the id of the tag.